# Use $cond within $match in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i've tried to use $cond within $match in one of the stages of an aggregation as shown below :

```
{ "$match" : { 
  "field1" : { 
                "$cond" : {
                   "if" : { "$eq" : [ "$id" , 1206]},
                   "then" : 0,
                   "else" : 1545001200
                }
             }, 
  "field2" : value2 }}
```

But i got this error :

```
Error:
Assert: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "unknown operator: $cond",
"code" : 2,
"codeName" : "BadValue"
} : aggregate failed
```

The mongodb version is 3.4.4.
Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Why to use these conditions inside `$match`? Do this using  normal `if` `else` or  either use `$redact` aggregation. But I am truly in favour of simple `if` `else`

Comment: can you show me how to use if else instead?

Comment: @med.tu - I think you want to do a `$project` instead of `$match`.

Comment: I am pretty much in a fix now. Do you want to filter or `$project` the output?

Answer (score 7):

You just have to reword the logic a little bit.

```js
{ $match: { $expr: {
    $or: [
        { $and: [
            { $eq: [ "$id", 1206 ] },
            { $eq: [ "$field1", 0 ] }
        ]},
        { $and: [
            { $ne: [ "$id", 1206 ] },
            { $eq: [ "$field1", 1545001200 ] }
        ]},
    ],
}}}
```

Logically, the two statements are equivalent:

- Match the document by checking `field1 == 0` if `id == 1206`, otherwise match the document by checking `field1 == 1545001200`
- Match the document if either (`id == 1206` and `field1 == 0`) or (`id != 1206` and `field1 == 1545001200`).

Comment: Looks like $expr cannot be used inside $match block. It throws $expr is unknown operator. Version is 4.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming across this later on down the road:

This won't work for 3.4.4. But in MongoDB 3.6 they introduced the $expr operator that lets you use $cond and other operations within a $match query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

For an example see iamfrank's answer.

Also as mentioned in the comments you *could* do this later down the pipeline. But ideally you'll want to filter out results as early on in the pipeline using $match in order to improve processing times.

Comment: This does not work in `4.2.5`. Error thrown is `"unknown operator: $expr"`.

Comment: Looks like I goofed writing the example without testing. Updated to refer to iamfrank's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless important details were left out of the question, I think you are complicating something simple. Filtering during a `$match` aggregation step is the natural expected thing it should do.

For this particular example, there are only two simple scenarios to match a document. There is no need to use any other operators, just define the two different mutually exclusive queries and put them in an `$or` logical operator:

```py
{'$match': {'$or': [
  {'id': 1206, 'field1': 0},
  {'id': {'$ne': 1206}, 'field1': 1545001200},
]}}
```